# How to get data from SQL Server from one environment to another environment?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a environment called (Local) and other (Back-up).

From back-up database I have some stored procedures as well as tables which are populated.

In my local I have those stored procedures and table but nothing is stored in them.

So I want to get data from my back-up environment to my local DB environment, how may I achieve this?

I am using SQL Server

Comment: I would create backup file from "backup environment" and restore it to "local".

Answer (score 3):

There are a few good options listed in other answers. But depending on how often you need to do this activity or how granular control you need, Red Gate's [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) let's you compare databases and determine what data should be moved, which direction. Very powerful and easy to use. It's not cheap: starts at $400US but there is a 14 day trial available.

I have no affiliation to them, I'm just a very satisfied customer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get only the data in the database, one way to do it in MS SQL Server Management Studio is to export the data from one source to another.

Right-Click on the source database, select "tasks", then select "export data" and follow the instructions of the wizard. It is possible you need to modify some settings such as "identity insert".

To handle the structure of the database, you can generate scripts, namely,
Right-Click on the source database, select "tasks", then select "generate scriptis"

In the end, you can always do a backup / restore of your "back up" db over your local db.
Right-click on the source database, select "tasks", then select "back up..." and follow the instructions of the wizard. In this case, you will want to back up to a file

Afterward, you can restore it using a similar way.
Right-click on the dest database, select "tasks", then select restore. In this case, you will want to select to restore from file.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 to be able to comment instead of editing answers of other people ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SSIS ("Import Data" from Management Studio) to copy the table data.  (in SQL Management Studio, right-click your DB and choose Tasks->Import)

The Stored Procedures are better (IMO) being imported via a SQL Script (in SQL Management Studio, right click the DB and choose Tasks, "Generate Scripts".  Note: getting your SPs via SQL will not import any permissions by default.

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest creating SSIS(ETL) package. It's very powerful tool and not Ad-hoc solution like Redgate SQL Data Compare or backup/restore.

In larger enviroinment I would recommend Replication, but it's much bigger topic.

Answer (score 0):

to export data from one DB to another if they have same schemas is very easy. u just have use the impot export wizard inbuild in ssms and specify the source and destination DB's and the select the list of tables to be copied

```
watch this video 

www.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DeDfhTPU7P-M&ei=DUhwULvhM4LPrQeY9oDoCA&usg=AFQjCNGA5a1o-yL9z-31EQQAQed-r5Pvlg&sig2=SiSTQ9tDackePFXw9-5vmw
```